# Determine whether the class library is called from a windows based application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, console, console-application

This is based on C#. I am having a classlibrary in which I would like to know specifically if its being called from a windows based application

I searched a lot but all I found was code to know if it was called from a Console application.
I only want to know if its called from a windows based application or not

Please Help

Comment: What difference would that make? Maybe it's possible t achieve the same effect without knowing if it's called from a WinExe or not.

Comment: well, there is difference. it can be called from any services not just windows based or console based. Or other wise you can say just to be on the safe side

Comment: Never look for a backdoor for info that can trivially be supplied by the user of your library.  Use a constructor argument or property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether the application is running as a service or system app and thus cannot display a dialogue, test the state of Environment.UserInteractive.

There is no easy way to determine if the application is a windows or cmd-based application. For example, I might build a winforms-based application that doesn't create a window and instead runs as command-line style application by not opening a window.

Two (not necessarily reliable) ways of testing if it's a windows-based app would be to test Application.OpenForms (if it contains forms, then it's a windows app) or Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() (if 0 args, assume it's a windows app).

If you absolutely need to know whether the app is a console or windows one, then you need to step out of the world of managed code and start delving into the exe file using unmanaged C++ code. There is just one byte difference between the two in the PE header of the exe file: Subsystem is set to 2 for a windows app and 3 for a cmd app. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/90493/en-us for details if you really want to do this.

Comment: The thing is that, I am looking for a way so that my libraries user wont have to give any inputs on that. If I'm using Environment.UserInteractive it will have to be given by my user(which is not prefered).

Comment: And I understand the difficulty of the fact that one can call a form in Console application. I'll look into Application.OpenForms. Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() are not a feasible soln since again the above mentioned issue will come

Comment: Also, I'm getting Environment.Userinteractive true for console and windows app.

Comment: Environment.UserInteractive will be true for both console and windoiws apps. As previously explained, it's only false for services and processes started prior to login.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you with " I am looking for a way so that my libraries user wont have to give any inputs on that". Your library can freely access all the mentioned properties and methods. No user imput is required.

Comment: see, for u to better understand, my project is a class library, say abc. my project will be used by other projects, say a windows based application "wba" and a console based application "cba". Now, if abc is used by wba or cba i need some indication that it is being used in a form(which is difficult). I dont want the user to check Environment.Userinteractive and inform my library about it. what i want is, my library abc should get the info on where its being used without having the developer of wba or cba passing anything to my library. I know its difficult, but if there is any vague idea pls

Comment: You can call Environment.UserInteractive from within your library code. There's no need for the user to pass it to you.